# Не правильно считывается строка через fgets()

Tags: c++, c, строки, файлы

```
#define STRING_SIZE 77
int main()
{
    FILE* list, * newFile;
    char str[STRING_SIZE];
    fopen_s(&list, "laptops.txt", "rt");
    int notesNum = 4;
    while (num < notesNum) {
        fgets(str, STRING_SIZE , list);
        printf("%d%s\n", num, str);
        num++;
    }
    fclose(list);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Содержимое файла laptops.txt:

Acer Note Light    2699 5.6 02.0x11.8x08.3 100 040 10.4 1 1024x0768 60 0.774

ASW ND5123T        3489 7.2 02.3x11.8x10.1 133 032 12.1 1 1024x0768 70 1.300

ARMNote TS80CD     3699 7.2 02.0x11.5x08.3 133 064 11.3 1 1024x0768 75 1.300

AST Ascentia H50   4499 7.5 02.3x11.3x09.0 133 040 11.3 1 0800x0600 70 0.774

> Ожидалось, что на экран построчно выведется содержимое файла laptops.txt. Вместо этого на экране было вот это:

[image]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Знаете, выложите ваш файл laptops.txt на какой-то файлообменник, я очень хочу на него посмотреть *именно в том виде, в котором у вас все не работает*. До того времени ответ удаляю.

Comment: @Harry https://dropmefiles.com/of5Yo

Answer (score 1):

После присланного файла все понятно. У вас длина строки в файле **строго** равна 76 символам, потом идет перевод строки. но размер вашего буфера -

```
#define STRING_SIZE 77
char str[STRING_SIZE];
```

77, т.е. символ новой строки писать уже некуда...

В результате у вас `fgets` вынужден считывать в качестве первой строки ровно 76 символов. и выводить их. Второе чтение считывает пустую строку, вернее. один `"\n"` - отсюда и пустая строка. Третье читает вторую строку неполностью, четвертое - пустую строку...

Сделайте

```
#define STRING_SIZE 80
```

и посмотрите на результат...

Comment: без \n все равно пропадает две строки. Его я добавил просто для наглядности, чтобы было видно какие строки пропадают

Comment: Добавил скриншот, что выводит без \n. Тут видно что в первый раз fgets() скопировал строку верно, а во второй раз можно увидеть что в конце есть только номер без строки

Comment: дело не в \n без него тоже считывает не то что хотелось

Answer (score 0):

Пример рабочего кода. Подробнее о функции чтения строк [здесь](http://all-ht.ru/inf/prog/c/func/fgets.html).

```
#include <stdio.h>  //Для printf, fgets, fopen, fclose, feof
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LEN 80 //длина принимаемой строки

int main (void)
{  
    FILE *mf;   //указатель на файл

    // указатель на область памяти, в которую будут помещаться считываемые строки
    char *str = (char*) malloc(LEN);

    mf = fopen("laptop.txt","rt");

    // Проверка открытия файла
    if (mf == NULL) {printf ("Ошибка\n"); return -1;}

    //Чтение (построчно) данных из файла в бесконечном цикле
    for(int cnt = 1;;++cnt){

        fgets (str,LEN*sizeof(*str),mf);  // Чтение одной строки  из файла

        if (feof(mf)){  //Проверка на конец файла или ошибку чтения
            printf ("\nЧтение файла закончено\n");
            break;}

        printf ("%d. %s",cnt,str);  //выводим считанную строку  на экран

    }

    fclose (mf);

    free(str);  //освобождаем память

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fgets (str,sizeof(str),mf)` - и вы пишете на ruSO - почему у меня читает такими мелкими кусочками?.. А вам поясняют, что раз `str` - это `char*`, то `sizeof(str)` - размер не выделенной памяти, а указателя, обычно 4/8 байт в зависимости от разрядности приложения...

Comment: @Harry, вы правы. Я забыл домножить память на длину строки в 'fgets(str,LEN*sizeof(*str),mf);'